How can I Find DNA sequence of promoter region of a gene?
I have a fungal sequence from Candida albicans, sequenced via Sanger sequencing, that I want to check for quality and contamination.
I have 2 questions:

Could I use Alignment ? or BLAST or Chromatogram analysis with Chromas? Which one is better than the others?
How can I Find the DNA sequence of the promoter region of a gene? and Where?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please restrict your question posts to a single, specific question. If you have multiple questions, please create multiple posts, one for each question.

Are you looking for a specific known promoter sequence, or any promoter sequence?

I'm looking for promoter sequence of PLB1 gene in candida albicans organism.

To find the promoter reginon of fungi, you can use the public database such as EPD or EPDnew.
EPD is a collection of eukaryotic promoters derived from published articles and EPDnew databases (HT-EPD) are the result of merging EPD promoters with in-house analysis of promoter-specific high-throughput data for selected organisms only.

Thanks for your response, But I couldn't find candida albicans in this database.
